# how to compare local files in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to read local files using javascript.Are there any methods available?  My understanding is that JavaScript cannot read local files.  What are the workarounds available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title says speech api`s and in your question you speak about local files.I will try to answer both.For the speech api try google`s webkit which is open source 
http://stiltsoft.com/blog/2013/05/google-chrome-how-to-use-the-web-speech-api/

for reading local files.try using Node.js` readFileSync method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.0.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (annyang) {
  // Let's define our first command. First the text we expect, and then the function it should call
  var commands = {
    'show tps report': function() {
      $('#tpsreport').animate({bottom: '-100px'});
    }
  };

  // Add our commands to annyang
  annyang.addCommands(commands);

  // Start listening. You can call this here, or attach this call to an event, button, etc.
  annyang.start();
}
</script>
```